# Why is !important overridden?

Tags: css

Why is the computed font-size `22.08px`(`1.38em`) rather than `16px`?

```css
.stec {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
#content p {
  font-size: 1.38em; /* why does this override !important? */
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="stec">
    <p>some paragraph text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`16px` is `!important` but it's not being applied. Here's the computed style window from the Chrome debugger:

> [image: computed style]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inherited styles have a very low precedence. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#directly-targeted-elements):

> Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence over inherited styles, regardless of the specificity of the inherited rule.

So, that's your problem; `.stec` and `#content p` don't target the same elements. `#content p` overrides the style *inherited* from `.stec`.

Consider the following example. You might expect the paragraph text to be red, inherited from its div parent... but it's not:

```css
div {
  color: red !important;
}
p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div> <!-- !important is applied here -->
  This text is red.
  <p>Were you expecting this text to be red too?</p> <!-- not here -->
</div>
```

It's also not about specificity, as others have mistakenly suggested. It's about whether the rule actually targets the appropriate element. Consider the following example:

```css
p {
  color: red !important;
}
#test {
  /* this is the more specific selector, yet it's overridden by !important */
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>red</p>
<p id="test">were you expecting blue?</p>
```

`p` and `#test` both apply directly to the second paragraph; so, there's an opportunity for `!important` to override something.